# How do I search pattern match with knex

Tags: javascript, rest, knex.js

I'm searching through an sql database using knex.js query builder and I'm trying to create a model that searches for all rows where the `title` has the input title I pass.

```
async function getByTitle(title) {
  const result = await db('recipes')
    .select('*')
    .whereRaw('LOWER(title) LIKE ?', title);
  return result;
}
```

This seems to only give the exact matches to the title instead of pattern matching it. For example, I have

```
test
test1
test2
test3
```

when title is `test`, I expect to get all that back, but instead I only get `test` back. I've searched through many similar questions and this seemed to be the solution, but this isn't working in my case.

Comment: if you pass in "test" as the pattern, you're going to match only "test" --- for LIKE clauses, you would typically use the wildcards `_` for a single char and `%` for a variable number of chars --- in your example, perhaps "test_" would do the job

Comment: Hmmm ok so i tried that and it didn't work, but the input will be the params from a request. The goal is that the user will be searching for a recipe, so maybe they'll put in chicken, and all the recipes returned should be anything with the word chicken in it. Is there a way find all rows under the column `title` that contains the word "chicken"

Comment: `"% chicken %"`

Answer (score 1):

Use wildcards to get all entries containing the supplied value

```
async function getByTitle(title) {
  const result = await db('recipes')
    .select('*')
    .whereILike("title", `%${title}%`)
  return result;
}
```